# trying to detect id the user is between the first 8 hours and next 8 hours or last 8 hours

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to create a log entry where i want to check if the user is visiting first time or 2nd or 3rd time or multiple times

In this case i am considering the time to be split into 8,16,26 so if the same user is coming back and forth in first 8 hours, it should only make one entry in db and if the user is again coming back in the next 8 hours it should make another entry and once the entry is made within the 8 hour slot, he can come and go multiple times but only 1 entry will be made

so in that case i am trying to use the code starting here

```
 var sessionRotated = dateConvert('local2Utc', now()).hour();
<cfif sessionRotated  LTE 8> <!--- first entry --->
    <cfset entry_1 = true>
</cfif>

<cfif sessionRotated  LTE 16 AND sessionRotated  gte 8> <!--- first entry --->
    <cfset entry_2 = true>
</cfif>

<cfif sessionRotated  LTE 16 and sessionRotated  GTE 24> <!--- first entry --->
    <cfset entry_3 = true>
</cfif>
```

but i am missing a logic here how can i use it along with the IPAddress

any idea

Comment: It's so simple to not worry about any of this and simply log every login.  What's the motivation for this?

Comment: Kinda unclear what you are asking for. You will have to store each visit per IP in a persistent table or map and then compare using `dateDiff("h", date1, date2)` to check if the difference is at least 8 to create another log entry. Your snippet doesn't fit the logic you are describing.

Comment: Int((dateConvert('local2Utc', now()).hour()-1)/8) will get you the slot. Then you just need to check for uniqueness between the slot and the IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

1. You're only looking at the hour of the current time.  This has no relation to the previous time a user visited your site.  You need dateDiff() in here somewhere
2. You'll have to store the last visit datetime in your database.
3. Optionally, you can update a cookie every time you get a new hit from this user and have that for your dateDiff()

Other points:
Cookies can be cleared.  This isn't foolproof.
IP Addresses can change.  VPN's, new connection at a different Starbucks, different computer, etc.  If you have a login system, that's a much better way to track a specific user.
Anytime you're looking at just the HOUR, you aren't considering first hit at 11am, next hit at 2pm.

Comment: i am not concerned for all scenarios, all i want is just not to pile up my log table with every entry being made to the link, all i need is keep them validated for 8 hours and after 8 hours just assign them a new session so for every 8 hour they can only have only entry instead of 50.

Comment: You can accomplish that by lengthening the session timeout to 8 hours.

Comment: Note, though, that increasing session timeout means they won't garbage collect as often, and this can utilize additional RAM, if that's a concern.